# npm windows missing write access

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm getting this message

`npm WARN checkPermissions Missing Write Access to D:\my\path\node_module\bcrypt`

while installing [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) package using `npm i bcrypt`

I tried executing the commands from `cmd` as an administrator and also from `powershell`, nothing worked.
I also cleared the cache `npm cache clean` and manually deleted `%AppData%/npm_cache` directory.

I'm using:
`npm 3.7.3`
`node 5.9.1`
`windows 7`

Why isn't npm getting the permission to write?

Note that npm can install and write other modules(i.e angular2,mongoose,express etc) just fine.

Comment: What permissions does the folder *really* have? I've had a few cases where folders ended up as SYSTEM as the *owner* (and thus no user owner-write, as might be assumed, even as an Administrator); depending on where the npm modules live it should probably be your own account for your profile (so you can own it all) or TrustedInstaller for Program Files (which allows Administrator write access).

Comment: tldr; my first step would just be to reset the Owner for the npm root.

Comment: I've given [write](http://imgur.com/FoqcIYD) permission to all the users/group of the node_modules directory(the one in my current project).
  

"reset the owner for the npm root" - didn't follow you.  

note that npm can install and write other modules just fine.

Comment: Assign the appropriate owner (yourself, or TrustedInstaller) for the NPM root directory/folder (modules is fine), recursively - doing it at the root is to ensure everything is consistent. The appropriate owner bestows all the required permissions without changing any other security access. Other modules is not related the specific permissions on a specific module/folder/file.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The target module folder wasn't even created, I created it myself and the installation went through.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was a permission/owner issue. I deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again without problems.

Comment: No still get "Missing write access"